# Phonegap detect if the phone is active

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I've been searching for a while now, and can't find anything for this with Phonegap only for Android or IOS.

So would be nice if someone knew how or if its even possible. 
Is there a way to check if the phone is in use/active, or if the phone is inactive/screen locked etc.?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that in PhoneGap, but natively it probably is possible. iOS turns of the accelerometer when the phone is locked/inactive, and that can be detected. There's also [UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable) event which will trigger on a lock event etc. I'm sure android has similar options, but nothing that's built into PhoneGap.

Comment: That's too bad, then I'll need to come up with a some sort of workaround to my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: You can find it via Events API http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html ... However, the app needs to be running at the foreground. Perhaps more info on http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_events_events.md.html

Comment: You have to create a plugin for that.

Comment: @jcesarmobile : I'm fairly new to Phonegap/Cordova, but not a bad idea to make it myself ;)

Comment: You could use a background services plugin (like https://github.com/phpsa/cbsp) and flag pause / resume events to know the state

Comment: Hi @MariusDjerv, did you find out something or finish your plugin yet? I am having the same need here.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can accomplish this by using two of the built-in phonegap events:

- [pause](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause) - this event is triggered once the application is put in the background (i.e. when it's not active)

Example:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

- [resume](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume) - and this one is triggered when the application is invoked back into the foreground (i.e. becomes active)

An example would be:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
  // Handle the resume event
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, I have been looking at this but as you say that this is only for the specific application. But I'm trying to check if the phone is active or not. The app will be running in the background most of the time either way. Similar to SCREEN.ON - SCREEN.OFF (Only this can happened while your on the phone.)

Comment: You can implement it this way:
If the phone has "resumed", consider it active, otherwise (i.e. "paused") mark it as "inactive". Do you think this will work ?

Comment: This is the way to go, if you want to check if your app is been put to the back. Lets say your app is A and a native app is B. A is open, B opens so A is background. Then this function will work.

'The pause event fires when the native platform puts the application into the background, typically when the user switches to a different application.'